# How do you gain access to global variables and functions from Javascript scripts imported from index.html and use them in a component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I am using Angular 6 and I have a private JavaScript library I need to use in the project. I am importing it in the index.html file. The project uses globally spaced functions. How do I access them inside of a component. Angular does not gives me an error and does not recognize them.

```
index.html
.....
<script src="https://somefile.js type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
.....

// has a function 
doXYZ()  in the global namespace


somecomponent.ts
......

ngOnInit() {
    doXYZ()  //try to call globally imported function
}
......
```

> ERROR: Cannot find name doXYZ when using `ng serve`

Comment: Could you provide more detail in addition to some form of source code please? Show us what you've tried to do, help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to access the global namespace on the `window` object.

Try accessing your desired function like this:

```
window['doXYZ']();
```

`window` is globally accessible.